# Why I do not see any props in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-props

I'm trying to pass some *props* to *class component* from *function component* via navigation.

At Function component I'm writing:

```
export default function StartScreen() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    function onButtonPress(){
       navigation.navigate("Main",{'test':'Test'});
   }
   
   return(
    <>
      <AnimatedTouchable onPress={onButtonPress}></AnimatedTouchable>
    </>
   )
}
```

At Class component I'm trying to access it at constructor but do not see any props:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props);
        console.log(this.props.test);
}
```

But the consol log is always:
**Object {}**

My App.js Looks like:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false
      }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Start" component={StartScreen} />    //this is function component
        <Stack.Screen name="Main" children={() => <Main />} />   //this is class component
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Does anybody can explain me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is much easier than I thought.
I just missed sending props

So, for anybody who may stumble over a similar problem, just check if you do not forget to add props to the component.

In my case I just changed code in App.js **from**:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Main" children={() => <Main />} />
```

**to:**

```
<Stack.Screen name="Main" children={(props) => <Main {...props} />} />
```

Comment: it gives me error "parameter@ props implicitly has any type?

Comment: @Shani74 - yes, if you are using TypeScript, you need determine which type of props you are expected to get there.

For example: 

type Props = {
    username:  string;
}

and then apply it for your props:  children={(props: Props) => ...

Answer (score 0):

the data your are passing is navigation params not props, they will live on the route prop on your screen do this to console them, also I would check the docs but I don't think you can access them in the constructor,

log then in component did mount

```js
componentDidMount(){
 console.log(this.props.route.params.test);
}
```

Comment: Console log in componentDidMount shows the same

`code log this.props - Object{}; log this.props.route.params - undefined `

Comment: @KirillKriachenko I missed that you have to wrap the child component in a withNavigation method, the way you're doing it is really not ideal as you're recreating your function component every time the screen is created this will lead to possible performance issues https://reactnavigation.org/docs/2.x/with-navigation/